# Anychart - Stock Chart Grouping Button

Tags: grouping, anychart

On most stock charts by default you will see a grouping button on the top left corner to group by minutes, hours, days, weeks. How to enable this feature in AnyChart? I've searched the docs thoroughly but couldn't find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The chart grouping parameters can be adjusted using the library API. [The article describes in detail](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Data_Grouping#overview) all aspects of the grouping feature and available options. Using the API you can implement any UI to switch the grouping, [just like in the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/A6q7Uj2v).